# Not working Laravel + Vuejs in laravel app

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

working with Laravel 5.7 and Vue Js. this is 
`app.js`

```
let Myheader = require('./components/Myheader.vue');
let Myfooter = require('./components/Myfooter.vue');

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components:{Myheader,Myfooter}
});
```

`blade.php file`

```
<body>
<div id="app">
<Myheader></Myheader>
<Myfooter></Myfooter>
</div>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>  
</body>
```

but when I run artisan serve command it is not displayed vue component. how can fix this problem?

Comment: You can't build Vue files with `artisan serve`. Try `npm run watch` or `npm run dev`. Be sure, you have `npm` installed. By the way, check your console output, should ne some errors there :)

Comment: yes, I have run `npm run watch` as well but error is here

Comment: and console output is this `[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. found in ---> <Myfooter> <Root>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are use Laravel Mix 4.0+, try adding `.default` to your requires. This is needed when you use CommonJS to import modules.

```
let Myheader = require('./components/Myheader.vue').default; 
let Myfooter = require('./components/Myfooter.vue').default;
```